# "findMethods" doesn't return expected results

Tags: call-graph, opal-framework

I'm trying to implement an analysis (extends DefaultOneStepAnalysis) to construct call graph in CHA algorithms. There are three parts of my code:

```
1) method "doAnalyze" to return the "BasicReport"
2) method "analyze" to find call edges for each method in the given project
3) class "AnalysisContext" to store the context and methods using in the analysis.
```

In 3), I use method "callBySignature" to find out cbsMethods of a method same as in "CHACallGraphExtractor" but it doesn't return expected result.
While I use the original OPAL's way to get cbsMethods in Extractor, the result is a set of methods.

Could you please help me to confirm where the problem is and how to solve it?
Thank you very much.

Regards,
Jiang

----Main Part of my code-------------------------------------------------

```
object CHACGAnalysis extends DefaultOneStepAnalysis { 
    ... ...
    override def doAnalyze(
                                  project: Project[URL],
                                  parameters: Seq[String] = List.empty,
                                  isInterrupted: () ⇒ Boolean
                                  ): BasicReport = {
    ... ...
      for {
          classFile <- project.allProjectClassFiles
          method <- classFile.methods
        } {
        analyze(project, methodToCellCompleter, classFile, method))
        }
    ... ...
   }

  def analyze(
               project: Project[URL],
               methodToCellCompleter: Map[(String,Method), CellCompleter[K, Set[Method]]],
               classFile: ClassFile,
               method: Method
               ): Unit = {
   … …
       val context = new AnalysisContext(project, classFile, method) 
       method.body.get.foreach((pc, instruction) ⇒
       instruction.opcode match {
       ... ...
           case INVOKEINTERFACE.opcode ⇒
                val INVOKEINTERFACE(declaringClass, name, descriptor) = instruction
                context.addCallEdge_VirtualCall(pc, declaringClass, name, descriptor, true,cell1)
           ... ...
         } 
… …
}

protected[this] class AnalysisContext(
                                         val project:   SomeProject,
                                         val classFile: ClassFile,
                                         val method:    Method
                                         ) {
    val classHierarchy = project.classHierarchy
    val cbsIndex = project.get(CallBySignatureResolutionKey)
    val statistics = project.get(IntStatisticsKey)
    val instantiableClasses = project.get(InstantiableClassesKey)
    val cache = new CallGraphCache[MethodSignature, scala.collection.Set[Method]](project)
private[AnalysisContext] def callBySignature(
                                                  declaringClassType: ObjectType,
                                                  name:               String,
                                                  descriptor:         MethodDescriptor
                                                  ): Set[Method] = {
      val cbsMethods = cbsIndex.findMethods(
        name,
        descriptor,
        declaringClassType
      )
      cbsMethods
   }
def addCallEdge_VirtualCall(
                                 pc: PC,
                                 declaringClassType: ObjectType,
                                 name: String,
                                 descriptor: MethodDescriptor,
                                 isInterfaceInvocation: Boolean          = false,
                                 cell1: CellCompleter[K, Set[Method]]
                                 ): Unit = {

      val cbsCalls =
        if (isInterfaceInvocation) {
          callBySignature(declaringClassType, name, descriptor)
        }
        else
          Set.empty[Method]

 … …
}
… …
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code to the question? That would help to clarify your question.

Comment: The original code is too complicated while I upload the main part of the code. I have also debugged it in OPAL to find why "cbsIndex.findMethods" couldn't find methods as expected. I found it comes from "propertyStore(method, CallBySignature.Key)" in CallBySignatureResolution.scala. As to this statement, the result of my code is "EP(XXXX,NoCBSTargets)" and the result of the original code is "EP(XXX,CBSTargets(XXX))". To go further

Comment: Is it possible that your analysis mode is a desktop application? You can use `project.analysisMode`to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the problem is due to "AnalysisMode"
After I resetting AnalysisMode into "CPA“ the question is solved.

I think I should always keep in mind what "AnalysisMode" should be used before I design the algorithm.

Thank you for your concern
Jiang